# .htaccess : redirect everything except a few folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have this problem:
I have an .htaccess file witch rewrites all my url's to index.php
i have an exception for a few folders.

THis words fine, but when a file doesn't exist in one of this folders he still does the rewrite. But he may not doe that.

How can i fix this problem?

My code :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(templates|images)/ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(favicon\.ico) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(templates|images|favicon\.ico) [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: This is weird.

When i go to the url manually, it's shows me a 404 error. but the index.php is called from this url (i can see this in my logs)

any idees?

Comment: I don't think you need the `!-f` or `!-d` or `!-l` there